# list the author from data who have the most posts .. wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I need to make page with list of authors who have a most post ..

like this:

admin (10 posts)
johan (9 posts)
Rob (8 posts)
saa (5 posts)
ahl (3 posts)
newa (1 posts)

I found this

```
<?php global $wpdb;?>
    <?php $usernames = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT display_name, user_url , user_login FROM $wpdb->users ORDER BY ID DESC LIMIT 5");

        foreach ($usernames as $username) {
          get_userdata($); 
                echo '<li><a href="'.$username->user_login.'">'.$username->display_name."</a></li>";
        }
    ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<ul>
<?php wp_list_authors('show_fullname=0&orderby=post_count'); ?>
</ul>
```

See this page: http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/wp_list_authors